# EDT performance is very slow triggering error shown

Tags: java, codenameone

I have used infinteScrollAdapter with connectionRequest from json to populate the components but sometime it gives the following error while it usually works well. What can be the problem here? If i run again it works fine but it hangs sometimes for quite a long time and then show this error

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] 0:0:0,0 - EDT performance is very slow triggering this exception!
[AWT-EventQueue-0] 0:0:0,1 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 1000
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
[AWT-EventQueue-0] 0:0:0,75 - EDT performance is very slow triggering this exception!
[AWT-EventQueue-0] 0:0:0,76 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 1000
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.addPointerEventWithTimestamp(Display.java:1678)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.pointerDragged(Display.java:1704)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.pointerDragged(CodenameOneImplementation.java:1957)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.pointerDragged(CodenameOneImplementation.java:1845)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.access$1900(JavaSEPort.java:160)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.mouseDragged(JavaSEPort.java:957)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6573)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3339)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6294)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4550)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.addPointerEventWithTimestamp(Display.java:1676)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.pointerDragged(Display.java:1704)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.pointerDragged(CodenameOneImplementation.java:1957)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.pointerDragged(CodenameOneImplementation.java:1845)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.access$1900(JavaSEPort.java:160)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.mouseDragged(JavaSEPort.java:957)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6573)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3339)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6294)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4550)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.addPointerEvent(Display.java:1637)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.pointerReleased(Display.java:1789)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.pointerReleased(CodenameOneImplementation.java:2123)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.pointerReleased(CodenameOneImplementation.java:1871)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.access$1600(JavaSEPort.java:160)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$C.mouseReleased(JavaSEPort.java:923)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

my code:

```
int sizethumb = 0;
        int sizethumb1 = 0;
        if (responsesImg.size() > 0) {

            sizethumb = largePlaceholder.getWidth();
            sizethumb1 = largePlaceholder.getHeight();
            findMainImg(f).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizethumb, sizethumb1));

            findMainImg(f).getAllStyles().setBgImage(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholder, newsImgFilename + "_0_ y", responsesImg.get(0).get("image_url"), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));

            mainImageImgViewer = null;
            mainImageImgViewer = findMainImg(f).getUnselectedStyle().getBgImage();
        }

        if (responsesImg != null) {
            if (responsesImg.size() > 1) {
                sizethumb = thumbnail.getWidth();
                sizethumb1 = thumbnail.getHeight();
                findNewsThumbnail1(f).getAllStyles().setBgImage(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholder, newsImgFilename + "_0_ x", responsesImg.get(1).get("image_url"), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));
                findNewsThumbnail1().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizethumb, sizethumb1));
                thumbnail1 = null;
                thumbnail1 = findNewsThumbnail1(f).getUnselectedStyle().getBgImage();
            }
            if (responsesImg.size() > 2) {
                findNewsThumbnail2().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizethumb, sizethumb1));
                System.out.println("thumbnail img " + responsesImg.get(2).get("image_url"));
                findNewsThumbnail2(f).getAllStyles().setBgImage(URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholder, newsImgFilename + "_0_ w", responsesImg.get(2).get("image_url"), URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));
                thumbnail2 = null;
                thumbnail2 = findNewsThumbnail2(f).getUnselectedStyle().getBgImage();
            } else if (responsesImg.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("null images");
            }
        }
```

my connection:

```
class MR extends ConnectionRequest {

private Map<String, Object> resultsdata;
private Vector<Map<String, Object>> responses;

@Override
protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
   JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
   resultsdata = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
   responses = (Vector<Map<String, Object>>) resultsdata.get("root");
   newsImageArray = new ArrayList();
   for (int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++) {
       Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) responses.get(i);
       newsDetailHome = (String) hm.get("details");
       newsDateHome = (String) hm.get("date");
       newsTimeHome = (String) hm.get("time");
                    newsTitleHome = (String) hm.get("title");

                    responsesImg = new Vector<>();
                    if (hm.get("photo").toString() != "[]") {
                        responsesImg = (Vector) hm.get("photo");
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                Dialog.show("Error msg", "The server returned the error code: " + code, "ok", null);
            }

            @Override
            protected void handleException(Exception err) {
                Dialog.show("Connection msg", "There was a connection error: " + err, "ok", null);
            }
        };

        MR r = new MR();
        r.setPost(false);
        if (newsIdValueFromHome == null) {
            r.setUrl("http://capitaleyedevelopment.com/~admin/traffic/api/news/getNewsDetails?news_id=" + newsIdValue);
        } else {
            r.setUrl("http://capitaleyedevelopment.com/~admin/traffic/api/news/getNewsDetails?news_id=" + newsIdValueFromHome);
        }
        r.setDuplicateSupported(true);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().shutdownSync();
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
```

EDT Detection

```
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
EDT violation detected!
Rendering frame took too long 344 milliseconds
Rendering frame took too long 156 milliseconds
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:404)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageWidth(JavaSEPort.java:3449)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.getWidth(Image.java:667)
    at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getWidth(EncodedImage.java:471)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$ScaleToFill.adaptImage(URLImage.java:81)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.run(URLImage.java:159)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:103)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:140)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:404)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageHeight(JavaSEPort.java:3460)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.getHeight(Image.java:681)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledLargerRatio(Image.java:877)
EDT violation detected!
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$ScaleToFill.adaptImage(URLImage.java:82)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.run(URLImage.java:159)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:103)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:140)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:404)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageWidth(JavaSEPort.java:3449)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.getWidth(Image.java:667)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledLargerRatio(Image.java:878)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$ScaleToFill.adaptImage(URLImage.java:82)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.run(URLImage.java:159)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:103)
EDT violation detected!
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:140)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:404)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageWidth(JavaSEPort.java:3449)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.getWidth(Image.java:667)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledLargerRatio(Image.java:882)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$ScaleToFill.adaptImage(URLImage.java:82)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.run(URLImage.java:159)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:103)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:140)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:404)
EDT violation detected!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageHeight(JavaSEPort.java:3460)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.getHeight(Image.java:681)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledLargerRatio(Image.java:882)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$ScaleToFill.adaptImage(URLImage.java:82)
    at com.codename1.ui.URLImage$DownloadCompleted.run(URLImage.java:159)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:103)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:140)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:404)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.scale(JavaSEPort.java:3479)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scale(Image.java:961)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledImpl(Image.java:931)
    at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaled(Image.java:896)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using for loading the content? This is caused by `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

Comment: i have updated above

Comment: Sorry, I meant your `InfiniteScrollAdapter` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of code there but its not all of it so I can't really comment on that. I did notice you shutdown the network every time which is wrong. You should only call shutdown in very extreme cases.

This exception reports that our event queue is completely full. That's an insane situation to reach and it can only be reached if the native code keeps sending events while the EDT is being held in place. Turn on the EDT violation detection tool in the simulator and it will probably point at the actual violation.

To learn more about the EDT check out the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html).

Comment: When i set EDT to full, it detects lots of exception but not particular lines. How can i solve the issue? I have updated the EDT exceptions above.

Comment: Its prints stack traces that should include line numbers that point to your code. If those are unclear I suggest posting some of that output as a followup question

Comment: i have already updated the stack traces above. The line no. shown in the stack trace point to the lines that doesnt make any sense like in the commented lines, curly braces or the codes which have nothing to do with the form having problem.

Comment: Those are all fine, are those the only exceptions you see there or is there more stuff that doesn't include the URLImage?

Comment: there are many more exceptions but all with urlImage. What are the reasons for those URLImages exceptions?

Comment: URLImage scales the image in the background thread. Doing that isn't an EDT violation but is flagged by the EDT violation since often the scaling code is reached by changes that are an EDT violation.